# Decimal.quantize raises InvalidOperation

Tags: python, python-3.4

looking at `Decimal` i tried to convert `pi` to various precisions. i can call `pi.quantize()` with the first two options below but it raises an `InvalidOperation` with the third option. the precision of `pi` is nowhere near that...

```
from decimal import Decimal

pi  = Decimal('3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445'
              '923078164062862089986280348253421170679')
print(pi) # prints same as the string above

# just print formatted
print('{:1.7f}'.format(pi))

print(pi.quantize(Decimal('1.0')))     # 3.1
print(pi.quantize(Decimal('1.00')))    # 3.14
print(pi.quantize(Decimal('1.000')))   # raises InvalidOperation
```

what is happening here? have i misunderstood what this function should do? why does this exception occur at `1.000` and not before/after?

the same exception happens with `'0.001'` as argument for `quantize`.

Comment: Could not replicate - works fine for me on Python 3.4.3 on Yosemite.

Comment: `python3 3.4.0-0ubuntu2 amd64` on `ubuntu 14.04.2`. hmmm...

Comment: That's not how this works. **The answer** is there *"for future reference"*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize):

> ...if the length of the coefficient after the quantize operation would be
>   greater than precision, then an `InvalidOperation` is signaled.

Therefore your precision must be set to `3`; to check this, try:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

print(getcontext().prec)
```

You should read through the documentation on [contexts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#context-objects) to understand what they're for and how to use them. For example, you could try:

```
from decimal import Context, Decimal, getcontext

...

print(pi.quantize(Decimal('1.000'), context=Context(prec=4)))
```

Comment: oh, you are right. i **did** check `DefaultContext`; there the precision was 12; but you statement prints 3. thanks! the fix is `ctx = getcontext(); ctx.prec = 12`, right?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist there are various options; I've added another to my answer. Again, read up on contexts to figure out what will work best for you.